# how to set default value for ChoiceParameterDefinition parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using jenkins Pipeline and trying to use parameters ( Inputs ) Like .e.g.

```
[$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: ['ADD','SHOW','DELETE','UPDATE','RESET'], description: 'Choose an Operation', name: ''].
```

How to set default value for ChoiceParameterDefinition ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Choice parameter doesn't have the option to use 'defaultValue' like f.e. `StringParameter` See also https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters.

However, the first choice in your list will be picked as the default. See also the help section when configuring parameters.

[image: Choice parameter help]

Example if you want to have the default value to be empty:

```
[$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition', choices: ['','ADD','SHOW','DELETE','UPDATE','RESET'], description: 'Choose something', name: '']
```